# GET HTTP operation via apache Camel fails when Rest Request URI too long

Tags: java, apache, rest, apache-camel, cxf

I am using apache rest CXF with camel in my project. There are number of cases where the length of request URI for rest is too longs and after a certain length camel always though HTTP operation failed exception like below 
with

```
statusCode: 400 
        at org.apache.camel.component.http.HttpProducer.populateHttpOperationFailedException(HttpProducer.java:230) ~[camel-http-2.13.1.jar:2.13.1] 
        at org.apache.camel.component.http.HttpProducer.process(HttpProducer.java:156) ~[camel-http-2.13.1.jar:2.13.1] 
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61) ~[camel-core-2.13.1.jar:2.13.1] 
        at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:113) ~[camel-core-2.13.1.jar:2.13.1] 
        at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:72) ~[camel-core-2.13.1.jar:2.13.1] 
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:398) ~[camel-core-2.13.1.jar:2.13.1] 
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191) ~[camel-core-2.13.1.jar:2.13.1] 
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:118) ~[camel-core-2.13.1.jar:2.13.1] 
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:80) ~[camel-core-2.13.1.jar:2.13.1] 
        at org.apache.camel.processor.ChoiceProcessor.process(ChoiceProcessor.java:111) ~[camel-core-2.13.1.jar:2.13.1] 
        at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:72) ~[camel-core-2.13.1.jar:2.13.1] 
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:398) ~[camel-core-2.13.1.jar:2.13.1] 
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191) ~[camel-core-2.13.1.jar:2.13.1]l 
        at org.apache.camel.processor.ChoiceProcessor.process(ChoiceProcessor.java:111) ~[camel-core-2.13.1.jar:2.13.1] 
        at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:72) ~[camel-core-2.13.1.jar:2.13.1] 
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:398) ~[camel-core-2.13.1.jar:2.13.1] 
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191) ~[camel-core-2.13.1.jar:2.13.1] 
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:118) ~[camel-core-2.13.1.jar:2.13.1] 
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:80) ~[camel-core-2.13.1.jar:2.13.1] 
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191) ~[camel-core-2.13.1.jar:2.13.1] 
        at org.apache.camel.component.seda.SedaConsumer.sendToConsumers(SedaConsumer.java:291) [camel-core-2.13.1.jar:2.13.1] 
        at org.apache.camel.component.seda.SedaConsumer.doRun(SedaConsumer.java:200) [camel-core-2.13.1.jar:2.13.1] 
        at org.apache.camel.component.seda.SedaConsumer.run(SedaConsumer.java:147) [camel-core-2.13.1.jar:2.13.1] 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_101] 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_101] 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_101]
```

So is there any way, we can pass the length parameter explicitly in header before sending the request or any other configuration for setting maximum length of request URI. For workaround i just replaced camel call with HttpConnection and it worked fine, this means camel has some restriction over requested URI length.

I placed the request at [link](https://notepad.pw/request123)

Camel code :

```
.choice()
                .when(header(ReservationConstant.CALL_ENDECA_FOR_LAR_FACETS).isEqualTo(Boolean.TRUE))
                .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant(org.apache.camel.component.http4.HttpMethods.GET))
                .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_PATH, constant(ReservationConstant.ENDECA_GUIDED_SEARCH_SERVICE))
                .setBody(simple(StringUtils.EMPTY))
                //.to("cxfrs:bean:endecaLocationKeyRSClient?throwExceptionOnFailure=false")
                .to("{{service.endeca.location.dimension.rest}}")
                //.process(endecaFacetProcessor)
                .bean(EndecaResponseBuilder.class, "getEndecaResponseForLARFacets")
                .end()
```

Comment: Please share your code and the URI that cases the issue to make it easier to help.

Comment: I have added the details in description.Please note the above request worked successfully via postman or browser.

Comment: Have you checked on the server side that Camel somehow truncates the url?

Comment: @SoucianceEqdamRashti I just verified, there is a issue while writing the request on bufferedOutPutstream at line this.outputStream.write(data, offset, length) of HttpConnection class. where default size of outputstream is 2048 and data length is 4398. Camel is internally using Apache HttpClient for invocation. Is there any way, i can override the size of this OutPutStream object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the issue wasn't because of the long URI but due to the fact that one of my header in the request was too large after i removed that header it started working